# How could I know what are the changes with the last update?

Tags: update

For each update I made I am just able to know which version my phone is get in to. How could I know what all changes are made by that update?

Answer (score 2):

On the Microsoft website, there are separate update histories for [8.x](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/basics/windows-phone-8-update-history) and [7.x](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/basics/update-history)

Comment: Having 8.10.12393.890, but there's no details regarding this in given source.

Comment: 8.10.12393.890 has not reached the "General Availability" milestone yet, so isn't included as a release.

Answer (score 0):

8.10.12393.890 is a minor update for the 8.1 Dev Preview. Microsoft didn't gave a change log.

However there are some websites that try to get a changelog:

- 8.10.12382.878: [WPCentral](http://www.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-81-picks-first-update-improves-battery-life-and-squashes-bugs), [NokiaPowerUser](http://www.nokiapoweruser.com/2014/05/15/latest-windows-phone-8-1-update-installation-experience-what-has-changed)
- 8.10.12393.890: [WPCentral](http://www.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-81-preview-updated-version-12393), [NokiaPowerUser](http://www.nokiapoweruser.com/2014/06/03/windows-phone-8-1-2nd-update-installation-experience-what-has-changed-unchanged)

Answer (score 0):

[There's a full, very thorough version history on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_version_history). It goes into more detail than the official changelogs on WindowsPhone.com and also includes info for the minor updates (though the latest update is currently listed as "Unknown changes").